# DirectX Debug Layer on Windows Phone 8

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, directx-11, windows-phone-8-emulator, sharpdx

I am currently developing an XAML with DirectX application for Windows Phone 8, using a DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid and SharpDX.

Since the application is somewhat unstable, I would like to activate the [DirectX Debug Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find all errors.

How can this be done with a Windows Phone 8 device or the emulator?

I am aware that I can set the debug flag when creating the device, but I have no idea if I have to install additional tools or software on my computer or the device, since I cannot see any errors in the attached debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers of SharpDX kindly directed me to the following [hack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jwm/archive/2013/04/07/10378961.aspx), which is necessary when using the DirectX debug layer with DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid.

However, I should mention here, that the breakpoint described in the article linked above, can crash the managed debugger on app switches, even if the breakpoint is disabled.